# Tk window not showing anything

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am making a game in python 3.4.2 with the tkinter module, yet for some reason the Tk window comes up yet none of my buttons or labels show up. Any ideas?
This is my code.

```
 root = Tk()
 frameone = Frame(root, width = 400, height = 400)

 lone = Label(frameone, text = 'NumberGuessingGame. Author: ************. Version: 6.0', fg = 'red')
 lone.grid(row = 0)

 ltwo = Label(frameone, text = 'This is a game in which you select your difficulty.', fg = 'red')
 ltwo.grid(row = 1)

 lthree = Label(frameone, text = 'Then the computer generates a number which you have to guess.', fg = 'red')
 lthree.grid(row = 2)

 lfour = Label(frameone, text = 'The computer then gives you a score', fg = 'red')
 lfour.grid(row = 3)

 buttonone = Button(frameone, text = 'Continue')
 buttonone.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

 root.mainloop()
```

I do have code after this just incase that matters.

Comment: Try to post minimal examples that show the problem.  In this case, root, frameone, and lone and lone.pack are sufficient.  The other widgets are just noise.  With the noise removed (or commented out), you might have more easily noticed that frameone.pack is missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the containing widget is not laid out, children widgets are not shown.

`pack`, `grid` or `place` the frame widget:

```
root = Tk()
frameone = Frame(root, width=400, height=400)
frameone.grid(row=0, column=0)  # <----
...
```